# Cogs Help In Discord Py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a command wherein if you react on the embed, the bot sends something back. If I add this code to a cog, it won't work. If possible, can you tell me why?

```
@bot.command(aliases=['test','t'])
async def Test(self, ctx):
 TestEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Definition", description="This is just a test embed", color=11027200)
 TestEmbed.add_field(name="\u200b", value="▹❁❁▹❁◃❁❁◃",inline=False)
 emojis = ['⬅️','➡️']

 TestEmbedAdd = await ctx.send(embed=TestEmbed)
 for emoji in emojis:
     await TestEmbedAdd.add_reaction(emoji)

 def check(reaction, user):
     return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['⬅️', '➡️']

 try:
     reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=5, check=check)
     if reaction.emoji == '➡️':
         await ctx.send("Reaction 2!")
     elif reaction.emoji == '⬅️':
         await ctx.send("Reaction 1!")

 except asyncio.TimeoutError:
     await ctx.send("Time is out!")
```

Comment: how doesn't it work? provide details. btw you missed a ' on line 1

Comment: Basically, if I react with the given reaction on the embed it doesn't send "Reaction 2!" or "Reaction 1!" back. It, however, sends the Timeout.

Comment: Oh, I see, let me try to re-edit the code and see if it works if I add the '.

Comment: I tried it and it still won't work.

Comment: I guess the reactions aren't the ones you expect them to be? I always suggest using the emoji's unicode codepoint for comparing discord default emojis, try printing str(reaction.emoji) and see what is printed

Comment: Sure, I'll do so.

Comment: It doesn't show anything if I print it. I should just use the unicode instead.

Comment: If this code is in a cog, you may need to use `self.bot` instead of just `bot`. So `await self.bot.wait_for(...)`

Comment: The code is not in a cog, since there is `@bot.command` instead of `@commands.command`

Comment: @ArthurCole if the prints don't work then the check is probably returning False, now what may cause that? probably the reaction.emoji is not actually the one in that list. try putting the print inside the check

Comment: Oh, let me try to do those things then.

Comment: @ArthurCole btw next time try to write better titles that summarize the question, in this case, it should have been something along the lines of "discord.py bot does not respond in wait_for" or something similar

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That is noted, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the people in the comment section, I have found the problem with my code. I had to change bot.command into commands.command. (I've tried both bot and command, and it still works splendidly). The other crucial thing I had to add was "self" under bot.wait_for. Without the self, the command wouldn't work. Thank you so much for the help.

```
@commands.command(aliases=['test','t'])
async def Testing(self, ctx):
 TestEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Definition", description="This is just a test embed", color=11027200)
 TestEmbed.add_field(name="\u200b", value="▹❁❁▹❁◃❁❁◃",inline=False)
 emojis = ['⬅️','➡️']

 TestEmbedAdd = await ctx.send(embed=TestEmbed)
 for emoji in emojis:
     await TestEmbedAdd.add_reaction(emoji)

 def check(reaction, user):
     return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['⬅️', '➡️']

 try:
     reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=5, check=check)
     if reaction.emoji == '➡️':
         await ctx.send("Reaction 2!")
     elif reaction.emoji == '⬅️':
         await ctx.send("Reaction 1!")

 except asyncio.TimeoutError:
     await ctx.send("Time is out!")
```

Answer (score -1):

you need @commands.command instead of @bot.command